# Expression Engine upload error

Tags: expressionengine

I want to ask about Expression Engine upload image. I have an error when I tried to upload content image.

This is the error message:

> Failed to upload the image, through Upload Location Class (6)

I don't know why this error happen, because it hasn't happened before,
and when I tried to upload for another content, it still error.

I use Expression Engine v2.8.1.

### Edit

I've found my problem, it appears that my disk on hosting server is full.

Comment: Can be closed for this reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use Channel Images add-on by any chance?

- Check correct upload directory is writeable (777)
- Try a different upload location
- Try a small image to upload
- Check that your host hasn't limited your total size on the upload folder
- Check your PHP max upload and post size isn't a blocker
- Turn on the EE debugger and see if that outputs anything helpful

Comment: Hi Peter, after i check on my hosting cp, it appear that my disk on hosting is full. Btw, thanks for your answer, i really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Channel Images.

My solution was to increase the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize values in my php.ini file, to allow larger files through, which seemed to work.